# Clean install of 12.04 over old 10.10 and only format some partitions

Tags: 10.10, partitioning, 12.04, re-installation, cleanup

[image: my current partition setup]

I want to install latest Ubuntu 12.04, once it gets released, **on top** of my actual 10.10. The main reason is that I get the "not supported" message, and cannot upgrade to newer distributions through update manager, because I could never solve some errors, so I want to do a fresh install

Please help me with some questions:

**1)** How should I do to reinstall 12.04 over my 10.10 without erasing /dev/sda3 contents, which stores all the backup info? (see image)

**2)** Are the partition sizes shown ok or should I increase/decrease any?

**3)** Is ok to format only /usr /var /tmp and /home? Should i format another to do a clean install?

**4)** What will happen with grub and other things when I install 12.04 over actual 10.10? Should I remove grub before launching installation?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the installer, choose the advanced partition option. You'll have to re-specify all your mount paths (`/dev/sda1` as `/`, `/dev/sda8` as `/home`, etc.). Select to format `sda1`. Also, reformat `/usr`, `/var`, and `/tmp` (or get rid of them altogether). **Do not reformat /home, or you'll lose all your data!**

I would use only two partitions: `/` and `/home`. More than that is overkill in my opinion unless you have very specific needs and are running a server. I recommend resizing things such that the space taken by `/usr`, `/var`, and `/tmp` is part of the `/` partition. Having many partitions really takes away from your ability to use your disk flexibly.

Comment: Thanks, I did what u wrote, all went ok, Ubuntu didn't format my ntfs partition, but grub didn't work. I had to re-install it again with liveCD, and all working great now. Thanks